# Class assignment operator= question

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

Say I have two classes, in two different headers, called:

```
class TestA
{
    public:
        int A;
};

class TestB
{
    public:
        int B;
};
```

And I want to give them both an assignment operator to each other, so it's like:

```
class TestB; //Prototype of B is insufficient to avoid error with A's assignment

class TestA
{
    public:
        int A;
        const TestA &operator=(const TestB& Copy){A = Copy.B; return *this;} 
};

class TestB
{
    public:
        int B;
        const TestB &operator=(const TestA& Copy){B = Copy.A; return *this;}
};
```

How do I do the above whilst avoiding the obvious error that will result from calling/using class TestB when it hasn't been defined yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have the function definitions in your files as written as that will require a circular dependency.

To solve, forward declare the classes and put their implementation in a separate files.

`A`'s header file:

```
// A.h

// forward declaration of B, you can now have
// pointers or references to B in this header file
class B;

class A
{
public:
    A& operator=(const B& b);
};
```

`A`'s implementation file:

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

A& A::operator=(const B& b)
{
   // implementation...
   return *this;
}
```

Follow the same basic structure for `B` as well.

Comment: You don't even need separate files, you just need to separate the class definition from the member function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If you include both header files in your `.cpp` file, it should work.  Make sure that you have a full definition of both classes in the header files.

Comment: I think the issue is because the operator= is inline rather than separate. Thank you though.